# split string by certain number and save the result as a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

So I have a string (string = "Cipher Programming - 101!"), I want to split it by six chars
(spaces and special symbols included) and store result as list in Python.

expected output: ['Cipher', ' Progr', 'amming', ' - 101', '!']

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, you probably don't want to call a Python variable 'string'

Comment: Tried to solve it with for loop

n = 6
string = "Cipher Programming - 101!"
str_size = len(string)
part_size = n
k = 0
for i in string:
    if k % part_size == 0:
        print()
    print(i, end="")
    k += 1

but I am trying to write the code inside function returning only list (without using print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a normal for loop will do the trick:

```
string = "Cipher Programming - 101!"
n = 6
[line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(string), n)]
```

Comment: It's actually a list comprehension, not a normal for loop.

Comment: @Bialomazur Yes, my bad

Comment: @AntónioRebelo what does the third line do? when I run it says line needs declaration. If you shortened your code, could you please upload the full version of it?

Comment: Check @Bialomazur 's solution for a more straightforward solution that is easier to understand. If you have not come across list-comprehensions I suggest you do so, this is what I used in that solution and if you haven't heard of them it can be quite tricky to understand how it works. I am not sure what "needs declaration" means but I think the code should work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above works very well - is very compact and elegant, but for sake of understanding it a bit better, I've decided to include an answer with a regular for-loop.

```
string = "Cipher Programming - 101!"  # can be any string (almost)

result = []
buff = ""
split_by = 6  # word length for each string inside of 'result'

for index, letter in enumerate(string):
    buff += letter

    # first append and then reset the buffer
    if (index + 1) % split_by == 0:
        result.append(buff)
        buff = ""

    # append the buffer containing the remaining letters
    elif len(string) - (index + 1) == 0:
        result.append(buff)

print(result) # output: ['Cipher', ' Progr', 'amming', ' - 101', '!']
```

Comment: Please see António Rebelo's answer for an elegant solution

Comment: @ArthurKing I have, please read my statement before the actual code. It was my intention to make the code longer with more 'baby-steps' involved. I think it plays together quite well with  António Rebelo's much shorter solution with a list-comprehension.